# How do I select random rows from a table with limit and no duplicates?

Tags: mysql, sql, random, duplicates, sql-order-by

I want to select 100 random rows from a mysql table. That is easy.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 100, 1;
```

When the user clicks a button I want the next 100 random rows but not any of the first 100 rows.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 100, 101;
```

And again.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 100, 201;
```

The problem is that the above query select duplicates. Is it possible to select only random rows that have not been selected before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is to pass an argument to `RAND()` - that is called the *seed*. As [explained in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand):

> One implication of this behavior is that for equal argument values, RAND(N) returns the same value each time, and thus produces a repeatable sequence of column values.

So, consider, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY RAND(123) LIMIT 100, 101;
```

The sort is repeatable as long as you give the same seed. Just make sure to change the seed when you start a sequence of searches.

Comment: You can also say `SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY RAND(RAND()) LIMIT 100, 101;` if you want to ensure a different seed each time...